# ScrollMagic & Requirejs error

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, scrollmagic

I need add scrollmagic.js whit requirejs on my project

**My structure file is**

```
/js
   /app
      main.js
   /lib
      debug.addIndicators.js
      jquery.js
      require.js
      ScrollMagic.js
   app.js
```

**my app.js is**

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
        "app": "../app"

    },

});

requirejs(["jquery"]);
requirejs(["app/main"]);
requirejs(["ScrollMagic"]);
requirejs(["debug.addIndicators"]);
```

**in head script loading**

```
<head>
    <script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app/main" src="js/lib/../app/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="ScrollMagic" src="js/lib/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
</head>
```

**my main.js is**

```
define(['jquery'], function() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery(function() { // wait for document ready
        // init controller
        var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({ loglevel: 3 });

        // build scene
        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ triggerElement: "#trigger", duration: 300, loglevel: 3 })
            .setPin("#target")
            .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
            .addTo(controller);

    });
});


});
```

**Into inspector I have this error and ScrollMagic not works**

```
main.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: ScrollMagic is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:6)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at ready (jquery.js:2)
```

I also tried change define in main.js

```
define(['jquery','ScrollMagic','debug.addIndicators'], function() {
```

same error into inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import ScrollMagic in your main.js like this:

```
define(['jquery', '/path/scrollmagic'], function(jQuery, ScrollMagic) {
   ....
   ....
});
```